# Выполнить зеркальную перестановку в группе рядом стоящих разрядов, количество которых и номер старшего разряда в группе задаются с клавиатуры

Tags: c++

В общем задача состоит в том, чтобы вывести двоичное представление числа типа long double, потом с клавиатуры принимать значения:
 1. количество для перестановки в группе рядом стоящих разрядов (num)
 2. номер старшего разряда.
После выполнить зеркальную перестановку в группе рядом стоящих разрядов.

Массивы или другие структуры данных использовать нельзя, только побитовые операции изменяющие само число.

Проблема в функции предназначенной для зеркальной перестановки в группе рядом стоящих разрядов (reverseLongDouble), она обнуляет первую половину бито числа вместо того чтобы сделать перестановки (саму функцию нашел в интернете, ломал голову чтобы понять что там твориться, не получилось). Прошу указать на ошибку или хотя бы объяснить что в этой функции к чему. Заранее спасибо.

Сам код:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

union type
{
    unsigned long long ll;
    long double d;
};

void output(unsigned long long x)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 8 * sizeof(x) - 1; i > -1; i--)
        printf("%d", x >> i & 1);
    printf("\n");
}

void printLongDouble(long double x)
{
    cout << endl << endl;
    {
        type m;
        m.d = x;
        for (int i = 8 * sizeof(m.ll) - 1; i > -1; i--)
            printf("%d", m.ll >> i & 1);
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void printChar(char input)
{
    cout << endl << endl;
    unsigned int bit;
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        bit = ((input >> (8 - i - 1)) & 1);
        cout << bit;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

unsigned int reverseLongDouble(long double inputLongDouble, int count, int num)
{
    unsigned long long shift = (unsigned long long)num - (unsigned long long)count + 1;
    type inLongDouble;
    inLongDouble.d = inputLongDouble;
    unsigned long long mask = ((1 << (unsigned long long)count) - 1) << shift;
    unsigned long long ext = (inLongDouble.ll & mask) >> shift;
    unsigned long long rev_ext = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    {
        rev_ext <<= 1;
        rev_ext |= ext & 1;
        ext >>= 1;
    }
    rev_ext <<= shift;
    return (inLongDouble.ll & ~mask) | rev_ext;
}

unsigned int reverseChar(unsigned int inputChar, int c, int n)
{
    int shift = n - c + 1;
    unsigned int mask = ((1 << c) - 1) << shift;
    unsigned int ext = (inputChar & mask) >> shift;
    unsigned int rev_ext = 0;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < c; ++i) {
        rev_ext <<= 1;
        rev_ext |= ext & 1;
        ext >>= 1;
    }
    rev_ext <<= shift;
    return (inputChar & ~mask) | rev_ext;
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    char inputChar;
    long double inputLongDouble;
    int m, t;
    do 
    {
        t = 0;
        cout << "Выберите с каким типом вы хотите работать: 1 - long double; 2 - char " << endl;
        cin >> m;
        if (m == 1)
        {
            cout << "Введите данные:\n";
            cin >> inputLongDouble;
            if ((inputLongDouble > -9223372036854775808.0) & (inputLongDouble < 9223372036854775807.0))
            {
                printLongDouble(inputLongDouble);
                int count;
                cout << "\nВведите количество для перестановки в группе рядом стоящих разрядов:";
                cin >> count;
                int num;
                cout << "\nВведите номер старшего разряда:";
                cin >> num;
                output(reverseLongDouble(inputLongDouble, count, num));
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "\nОшибка!!!\n";
            }
        }
        else if (m == 2)
        {
            cout << "Введите данные:\n";
            cin >> inputChar;
            if ((inputChar > -128) & (inputChar < 127))
            {
                printChar(inputChar);
                int count;
                cout << "Введите разрядов количество для перестановки в группе рядом стоящих разрядов: ";
                scanf_s("%d", &count);
                int num;
                cout << "Введите номер старшего разряда: ";
                scanf_s("%d", &num);
                char reversed = reverseChar(inputChar, count, num);
                printf("\n");
                printf("%u\n", reversed);
                printChar(reversed);
            }
            else 
            {
                cout << "\nОшибка!!!\n";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "\nОшибка!!!\n";
        }
        system("pause");
        cout << "Хотите продолжить? да - 1; нет - 0\n";
        cin >> t;
        system("cls");
    } 
    while (t != 0);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тело функции верное, а вот что она возвращает???
32-битное значение - поэтому старшая половина и пропала.

Замените `unsigned int` на `unsigned long long reverseLongDouble...`

Что творится в функции:
Пусть count = 4, num = 6, возьмем для простоты 8 бит, обозначим биты буквами.

```
 ABCDEFGH
```

т.е. нам нужно развернуть BCDE, не трогая остальное

```
 shift = 3 (длина хвоста FGH)
 mask = 00001111 << 3 = 01111000  //маска для нужных битов
 ext = (ABCDEFGH & 01111000) >> 3 = 0000BCDE   //выделили, сдвинули вправо, чтобы ничего не мешало
 revext = 0000EDCB  //после цикла биты занесены в обратном порядке
 rev_ext <<= shift = 0EDCB000
 ABCDEFGH & !mask = A0000FGH //сбросили нужную часть
 A0000FGH | 0EDCB000 = AEDCBFGH   //и вставили развернутую
```

Comment: Спасибо, заработало. (И ошибка оказалась там, где ждешь меньше всего, проблема одна -- я невнимателен)